# `ext4lazyinit` after extending partition with `gparted`

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, gparted, ext4

I just extended a large (now 2 TiB) `ext4`-partition on a regular HDD to the left, using `gparted`. It took 5 hours to complete, but went well. Now, after mounting the filesystem, `ext4lazyinit` is running in the background, writing on that specific HDD with speeds of 4-6 KiB. What is it doing? Internet says, `ext4lazyinit` zeroes something out. Do I have to worry about my data?

Comment: It *sounds* like it's initialising the newly extended space, which I guess amounts to zeroing the data so it knows what is there. Since you extended the partition, I'm going to guess that the space was already empty.

Comment: But it's only zeoring areas where no files of that mounted `ext4` filesystems are, right? So, e.g., it's only zeroing out free space, right? And not overwriting / deleting any files? The space I grew that ext4 partition on was previously used by another partition which I shrunk before growing the `ext4` partition. So possibly it was not all zeroes.

Comment: It's zeroing the space allocated to the partition. The shrunk partition had enough empty/free space to shrink, so there can't have been any files in those sectors.

Comment: Let me clarify this: Before making any changes, I had a large HFS partition followed by a small ext4 partition. I shrunk the HFS partition and grew the ext4 partition to the left, now I have a small HFS partition followed by a large ext4 partition. So yes, all the files that were on the space that was used by HFS before and is now used by ext4 were moved off it before. But my ext4 partition also contains 1.3 TiB of data, according to `df -h`. And I just wanted to make sure that `ext4lazyinit` does not overwrite some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gparted must have done a faster "lazy" format of the new ext4 space, and now upon mounting it's finishing the work. These options from `mke2fs` should explain:

```
lazy_itable_init[= <0 to disable, 1 to enable>]
                      If  enabled  and  the  uninit_bg feature is enabled, the
                      inode table will not be  fully  initialized  by  mke2fs.
                      This speeds up filesystem initialization noticeably, but
                      it  requires  the  kernel  to  finish  initializing  the
                      filesystem  in  the  background  when  the filesystem is
                      first mounted.  If  the  option  value  is  omitted,  it
                      defaults to 1 to enable lazy inode table zeroing.

lazy_journal_init[= <0 to disable, 1 to enable>]
                      If  enabled,  the journal inode will not be fully zeroed
                      out by mke2fs.  This speeds up filesystem initialization
                      noticeably,  but  carries  some small risk if the system
                      crashes before the journal has been overwritten entirely
                      one  time.   If the option value is omitted, it defaults
                      to 1 to enable lazy journal inode zeroing.
```